# Regex - Extract string patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I have many strings like these

```
/test/v1/3908643GASF/item
/test/v1/343569/item/AAAS45663/document
/test/v2/field/1230FRE/item
...
```

For each one I need to extract the defined pattern like these

```
/test/v1/{Value}/item
/test/v1/{Value}/item/{Value}/document
/test/v2/field/{Value}/item
```

The value can be a guid or something else, Can I match the given string patterns with input paths with regex?

I wrote just this code but I don't konw how to match input paths with patterns. The result should be the pattern. Thank you

```
string pattern1 = "/test/v1/{Value}/item";
string pattern2 = "/test/v1/{Value}/item/{Value}/document";
string pattern3 = "/test/v2/field/{Value}/item";

List<string> paths = new List<string>();
List<string> matched = new List<string>();    

paths.Add("/test/v1/3908643GASF/item");
paths.Add("/test/v1/343569/item/AAAS45663/document");
paths.Add("/test/v1/343569/item/AAAS45664/document");
paths.Add("/test/v1/123444/item/AAAS45688/document");
paths.Add("/test/v2/field/1230FRE/item");


foreach (var path in paths)
{


}
```

Comment: I think you are searching for something like this: 
/(\/test\/v1\/[a-z, A-Z]+\/item)/
/(\/test\/v1\/[a-z, A-Z]+\/item\/[a-z, A-Z]+\/document)/

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using regex alone. You can probably try:

```
(\w+)\/\w+(?<=\/item)(\/(\w+)\/)?
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`(\w+)`** - Represents a capturing group matching a word character one or more time. This group captures our required result.
>
> **`\/\w+(?<=\/item)`** - Represents a positive look-behind matching the characters before `\items`.
>
> **`$1`** - Captured group 1 contains the required information you're expecting.
>
> **`(\/(\w+)\/)?`** - Represents the second and third capturing group capturing if after item some other values is present or not.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/AjOLEr/2)

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

**Sample implementation in C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(\w+)\/\w+(?<=\/item)(\/(\w+)\/)?";
        string input = @"/test/v1/3908643GASF/item
/test/v1/343569/item/AAAS45663/document
/test/v2/field/1230FRE/item";
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.Write(m.Groups[1].Value + " ");
            if(m.Groups[3].Value != null)
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy76zVqTU)

Comment: Hmm downvoter!!!I can improve my answer if there is something wrong.